# Is wallmart API allows HTML format in product description?

Tags: walmart-api

I am using wallmart API to import products from the custom site. I want to display description with the same HTML format in my site. Is wall mart allow HTML format and show as it like my site in the description field?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can upload product with same description on Walmart but only one restriction on Walmart is that they accept only 4000 characters in description .

if you are using XML format to upload product on Walmart kindly send description concatenate with CDATA .

```
  eg .
  I am using php so my code like this 

  <![CDATA[' .$desciption. ']]>
```